# Two entries are getting inserted from Android -> PHP -> MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my app, I am trying to copy an audio file to a server and am inserting into a mysql database table. The issue is that there are two entries getting created in the database table for every record I insert. Not sure what is the issue. Kindly help. I have pasted the relevant code below.

PHP code:

```
    <?php
        $audNm=$_GET['audNm'];

        // Where the file is going to be placed 
        $target_path = "/home/xxxxxx/public_html/projects/xxxxxx/androidaudio/"; 

        $audio = $audNm.".3gp";
        $target_path = $target_path . $audio ;

        mysql_connect("localhost","xxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO audio (audionm) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($audNm)."')");
// Multiple entries are inserted here

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";

        } 
        else{

            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
            echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
            echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
        }

        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Android code:

```
        urlString = "http://xxxxxxxx/projects/xxxx/audioinsert.php?audNm="+audFileNm;
        timeout= 7000;
        Log.d(Globals.TAG,urlch);
        //File upload logic
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(mAudioFileName));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlch); //to change
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + mAudioFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            Log.d(Globals.TAG,"headers are written");
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams

            httpclientAudio = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclientAudio.getParams().setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout);

            httppostAudio = new HttpPost(urlch);
            httppostAudio.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            responseAudio = httpclientAudio.execute(httppostAudio);

            entityAudio = responseAudio.getEntity();
            isAudio = entityAudio.getContent();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isAudio));

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }

            Log.d(Globals.TAG, "File is written");
//These logs are written only once. So am not calling this code twice
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            Log.d(Globals.TAG,"response audio:"+ total);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            mResponseAudio=Globals.NULLRESPONSE;
            Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            mResponseAudio=Globals.NULLRESPONSE;
            Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mResponseAudio=Globals.NULLRESPONSE;
        }


    try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
            String str;            
            while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.d(Globals.TAG,"Server Response"+str);
                if (str.contains("has been uploaded")){
                    mResponseAudio=Globals.GOODRESPONSE;
                }
            }

            inStream.close();
```

Comment: I'm no android developer but your Android code is 99.5% likely calling the web URL twice because I see no looping in your PHP script and `mysql_query()` is only being called once.

Comment: Thanks, but the logs statements from my android code are printed only once. So not sure if url is getting called twice..I even put brake points in code to check this out

Comment: Can you add a MySQL column called `time_log` with varchar(200) and simply fill it with `microtime(true)`? If the microtime is the same for both inserts then there is something screwy with mysql_query. If the microtimes are different then `mysql_query()` is being called twice. `"INSERT INTO audio (audionm, time_log) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($audNm)."', '".microtime(true)."')"`

Comment: okk. I ll do that and get back to you. One thing I should mention is that from php two logs are getting printed. Once for file upload failed and then file upload success.

Comment: Sounds good. I don't like to jump to conclusions but what you explain means that the PHP script is getting called twice after all. You should move `mysql_query()` inside the `if(move_uploaded_file` curly braces. Then you can move on to the mystery of why the upload is failing in the first place and then what is causing the second attempt

Comment: Is the data getting written properly both times? It looks like you are calling the form 2x: once as `HttpURLConnection` and once as `HttpPost`

Comment: @monkeyzeus.. Thanks. Moving the insert statement within the if statement worked for me. Still not sure what the exact issue was. But anyway, am happy that its working now. I have given you an upvote. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like to jump to conclusions but what you explain means that the PHP script is getting called twice after all. You should move `mysql_query()` inside the `if(move_uploaded_file` curly braces.

Then you can move on to the mystery of why the upload is failing in the first place and then what is causing the second attempt.